# dotnet core web api exception handling

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, unhandled-exception

The Main method in Program.cs in my dotnet **core** web api project has the following code.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var logger = LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
    try
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //NLog: catch setup errors
        logger.Error(ex, "An exception occurred during application start.");
        throw;
    }
}
```

I also setup an exception handling middleware like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(HandleExceptionMiddleware));
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Should I also add a `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` ? to the `Main` method - since dotnet core web api is a console application?. Do I lose/gain any chances of trapping exceptions without this?

Answer (score 0):

By adding try/catch in Program.cs you will end up catching app's start-up exceptions which i don't believe you should handle those exceptions because in any case if your app is not able to start so what will be the point .
Regarding to the App domain exception handling the answer is no , you don't need to handle them due to dotnet core built-in exception handling as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2) any exception that your app is not handling is being handled by the dotnet itself .
In short , let the app have a clean start-up and let it throw it's exceptions and then you can always check the *dotnet run* 's console for any exceptions .